# Adding new column to dataframe with month extracted from date Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image: data set]
I am trying to add a new column to a dataframe in Spark. I have a clean dataset (dfClean) with a column called "Fecha ingreso" that has a date and I want to extract the month from this column and add a new column that only has the month.
I tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import month

dfCleanMonth = dfClean.withColumn('Month',month('Fecha ingreso'))
dfCleanMonth.display()
```

but it's not adding any columns, even though it is not giving any errors. Does anybody know how I can fix it? I have looked online but can't seem to find the error.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show schema or sample data from dfClean?

Comment: of course, sorry! I added it to the question :)